# How can I get my first epic mount in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm close to level 85 and I want to know the easiest way to get my first epic mount that's different from the common mounts I can buy from vendors.

Which one should I go for? And how can I obtain it?

I'm a troll hunter.

Comment: Do you mean a flying epic mount? The ground one has been available to you since level 40. I think you could also buy the slower of the flying epic mounts at 80.

Comment: @Anna I want one of those beautiful dragons or something different from those plain mounts I can buy from common vendors.

Comment: @Anna Could you please point out where can I buy some of these flying epic mounts available on level 80 that you have mentioned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find detailed information on available mounts [at WoWpedia](http://www.wowpedia.org/Mounts). I'm not going to list *all* available mounts here, but you can find them all at that page. I'll try to summarize the general approaches you can take to getting a more exciting epic flying mount.

Basic wyverns are available from vendors when you hit level 70 and buy the Artisan (300) flying skill. Other mounts like the various drakes are typically available as faction mounts or rare drops.

Some are boss drops such as the [Bronze Drake](http://www.wowpedia.org/Reins_of_the_Bronze_Drake), others are reputation rewards such as the [Netherwing Drake Mounts](http://www.wowpedia.org/Netherwing_drake_mounts) or the [Red Drake](http://www.wowpedia.org/Reins_of_the_Red_Drake). If you're a tailor, you can craft a [flying carpet](http://www.wowpedia.org/Magnificent_Flying_Carpet) or its [winterized version](http://www.wowpedia.org/Frosty_Flying_Carpet). Engineers and alchemists can also create flying mounts for themselves.

You can also buy [this blue wind rider](http://www.wowpedia.org/Armored_Blue_Wind_Rider) from Dalaran, but it's not terribly different from the common mounts except in colour.

Last but not least, there are mounts like the [Violet Proto-drake](http://www.wowpedia.org/Reins_of_the_Violet_Proto-Drake) that are awarded for getting certain achievements.

As you can see, the list of options is long and varied. Since you're nearing level 85, pretty much any of these should be available to you at least as far as plain level requirements go. Which mount you should go for first depends entirely on what you feel like getting and how much time/gold you're prepared to spend to do it.

Comment: Is WoWwiki still being updated? I thought that most of the folks behind it had migrated over to WoWpedia (which is, I believe, the official Blizzard wiki)

Comment: @RavenDreamer Oh yeah, I keep forgetting about that. Updated links. Thanks!

Comment: @AnnaLear Thanks, I think I'm going to build reputation to get Netherwing Drake Mounts, as they are cool and I think it will be easier than wait for some boss to drop and the loot be awarded to me.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest mount to get that is epic is the Bronze Drake. To ride this mount you will need to purchase Artisan Riding (300) from a flying trainer. You will find the bronze Drake in the Culling of Stratholme Dungeon on Heroic difficulty. On heroic you will be timed so taking a tank and a healer from your guild will make it easier on you. Once you are through the last corridor of the dungeon, the final boss is to the right, but to the left you will find the other boss who drops this Drake 100% of the time.

Comment: I got that one as my first special mount, following Anna's answer :-) Another important information is that you need to beat that boss under 25 minutes, because he leaves when the 25 minutes countdown is over.